# if statement is terminating program or not working

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to write a code that will set up a tour and reservation for a user. The available times are `10`, `1` and `3`. If the user inputs a time that isn't that they are given another chance where I am to assume that they will input a correct time. However, when running my code, if I put in a correct time during the first or second time it will end. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Here is my code.

```
System.out.print("Enter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
newTime = keyboard.nextInt();
if(newTime != 10 && newTime != 1 && newTime != 3)
{
    System.out.print("\nTime entered is invalid\nEnter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
}
else if (newTime == 10 || newTime == 1 || newTime == 3)
{
   newTime = keyboard.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("\n\nTour information");
```

The line with Tour Information will never be displayed.

Comment: So, if the time *is* valid, you pause the program to wait for more user input? Putting aside that I don't think that's what you want to do, did you try typing a second number? Your print statement isn't even inside a conditional block, so it should execute no matter what, as long as you get past those `nextInt` calls, which will block your program indefinitely.

Comment: You should check the condition even in else if block after taking input.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues in your code:

-In the second if statement the value of newTime is not updated. You ask for a prompt to re-enter a value but you are not capturing it and the condition will evaluate with the previous value entered. What you should do is calling the nextInt() in the first if block just after the prompt.

-Secondly you might want to use a while loop with a boolean flag to control the flow and achieve the intended goal. Something like this:

```
boolean rightTime = false;
System.out.print("Enter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
while(!rightTime) {
    System.out.print("\nTime entered is invalid\nEnter the time (10, 1 or 3): ")
    newTime = keyboard.nextInt();
    rightTime = (newTime == 10 || newTime == 3 || newTime == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly reworked version of your code

```
    System.out.print("Enter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int newTime = scanner.nextInt();
    if(newTime != 10 && newTime != 1 && newTime != 3)
    {
        System.out.println("\nTime entered is invalid\nEnter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
    }
    else
    {
        newTime = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n\nTour information");
    }

}
```

This works to what you have specified in your question

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you want to ask for the right time? I'm going to take a guess here and assume you want to keep asking until the user inputs the right time. You want to use a loop in this case.

```
System.out.print("Enter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
newTime = keyboard.nextInt();
//If the user inputs an in incorrect hour, then loop until the user inputs a correct time:
while (newTime != 10 && newTime != 1 && newTime != 3) {
    System.out.print("\nTime entered is invalid\nEnter the time (10, 1 or 3): ");
    newTime = keyboard.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("\n\nTour information");
```